# How is it possible that Keras metrics are inconsistent with loss?

Tags: debugging, keras

I'm not entirely sure yet how to reproduce this in a toy example, and the real code is too cumbersome to post here. But I'm in a situation where I have keras model and call
`loss = 'mae' # or 'mse'`
`model.compile(loss=loss, optimizer='Adam', metrics=[loss])`. Then (with no further calls to compile), call `model.fit(...)` and see that the loss doesn't match the metric even though they are reporting the same thing!

I'm baffled if anyone has seen something like this before please let me know what could be causing it. Thank you!

P.S. I will try to amend post soon when I figure out how to reproduce in tiny example.

Comment: This question is unanswerable without a self-contained example.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out there were extra error terms being added to the loss by a colleague, in the form of soft constraints (e.g. kernel regularizers). When I removed them I had expected behavior again.